# Integrating Laravel app into Joomla CMS

Tags: laravel, joomla, laravel-5, jumi

I would like to build a custom application in Laravel framework and include it in Joomla.

What I would like to do is to replace central content of Joomla with application served from content.

Joomla url: http://www.joomlasite.com/campaign-directory -> should show content from laravel url: http://www.joomlasite.com/laravel/directory/showall

I noticed component Joomi for Joomla, but Iam not sure if this component will be able to do that.

Please advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean Jumi, and yes, I think that Jumi can do what you want, but I believe there are other easier ways to achieve what you need to do. What you can do is use the iFrame Wrapper component in Joomla to "wrap" your lavarel application and display it in Joomla. Try that before using a Jumi if possible.

Comment: Hey, thanks for feedback. I saw this wrapper possibility but I guess this is not a good option for SEO proposes. Any comment on that aspect?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done.

1. Create your site/page in Laravel
2. Add it to your Joomla website as a
   new Component
3. Add the new Component to a menu

So, all of the MVC files from Laravel go into the new Component's directory. For example, /home/public_html/www.yourjoomlawebsite.net/components/com_laravelpage. There are several steps involved in creating a Component correctly. Here is the documentation for it -- https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component